# High correlation between residuals and fitted values in a linear mixed effect model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, residuals

I am doing behavioural research on dragonfly larvae and I am trying to answer the question "Is there a behavioural difference between males and females and between species? + Do the difference between males and females change according to the species?" The behavioural data I have is the total distance moved by each individual in 15 minutes. I tested some of the individuals twice.

I asked my question to the model as:

```
lmer(Distance.moved~Sex*Species+StartTime+(1|Pond)+(1|ID), data)
```

The residuals are normally distributed, but when I plot the residuals vs fitted

```
scatter.smooth(fitted(mod1), resid(mod1))
```

they are correlated. And here is the summary of my model:

```
REML criterion at convergence: 2705.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.91074 -0.42168  0.00311  0.43850  1.91074 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 37701    194.2   
 Pond     (Intercept) 18463    135.9   
 Residual             28702    169.4   
Number of obs: 203, groups:  ID, 181; Pond, 10

Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                       930.84     253.64   137.35   3.670 0.000346 ***
SpeciesA.subarctica              -931.69     262.58   144.60  -3.548 0.000523 ***
SpeciesAnax Imperator           -1278.96     259.20   127.41  -4.934 2.46e-06 ***
SpeciesC.aenea                   -825.90     239.24   124.89  -3.452 0.000760 ***
SpeciesL.dubia                   -837.71     217.05   111.40  -3.860 0.000191 ***
SpeciesLibelluda quadrimaculata   374.43     281.43   170.47   1.330 0.185149    
SexMale                         -1194.92     240.57   130.49  -4.967 2.09e-06 ***
Start.x                            43.94      10.72    88.83   4.100 9.11e-05 ***
SpeciesAnax Imperator:SexMale    1295.40     358.64   119.41   3.612 0.000446 ***
SpeciesC.aenea:SexMale           1473.98     290.80   148.03   5.069 1.18e-06 ***
SpeciesL.dubia:SexMale           1171.85     245.86   129.44   4.766 4.97e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) SpcsA. SpcsAI SpcsC. SpcsL. SpcsLq SexMal Strt.x SAI:SM SC.:SM
SpcsA.sbrct -0.679                                                               
SpcsAnxImpr -0.675  0.671                                                        
SpeciesC.an -0.754  0.726  0.761                                                 
SpeciesL.db -0.828  0.807  0.820  0.887                                          
SpcsLblldqd  0.053 -0.005  0.019  0.008 -0.003                                   
SexMale     -0.741  0.728  0.756  0.808  0.884 -0.160                            
Start.x     -0.542  0.014 -0.009  0.031  0.030 -0.098  0.016                     
SpcsAImp:SM  0.485 -0.488 -0.708 -0.541 -0.592  0.105 -0.670  0.011              
SpcsC.n:SxM  0.601 -0.602 -0.627 -0.820 -0.731  0.130 -0.828  0.009  0.555       
SpcsL.db:SM  0.729 -0.716 -0.747 -0.796 -0.890  0.155 -0.985 -0.014  0.661  0.815
fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients
```

I have 6 species in my dataset, I tested 189 individuals from one species (L. dubia), but only 7,8,12,4,3 from the other five species.

How would you ask my research question with a model? Can I use this model with unequal sample sizes and if not, why not? Am I violating the assumption of homogeneity by using unequal sample sizes? Can I trust the results the model is giving when I am violating one of the model's assumptions?

Thank you for reading my question
I am new to modelling and I would really appreciate any help :)